# Should I use just one Session in my application based on HornetQ?

Tags: java, session, hornetq

In application based on HornetQ engine I intend to create multiple Producers and Consumers.
I have learned, that I should reuse resources as much as possible thanks to [this page](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ShouldIcacheJMSconnectionsandJMSsessions).

Does that mean, that for my application I should crate one and exactly one ConnectionFactory, one Connection, one Session and then (using this Session object) creating as many Producers/Consumers as I want?

That shouldn't be hard, but I'm not sure if this is the proper approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best rule of thumb for minimum resource usage is to use the fewest constructs as possible while remaining thread safe. Accordingly:

1. Connection Factories are thread safe: One per JMS server (or one per JMS server per destination type for topics and queues)
2. Connections are thread safe: Depending on the application architecture, you may be able to use one connection, but I would not bend over backwards to do this.
3. Sessions and all constructs below the session are **NOT** thread safe: You will need one session per concurrent thread (or per transaction if you think about it that way).

Based on that, hopefully you can strike a balance between an elegant architecture and low resource utilization.

Comment: side q, is it safe to create 2x producers from the same session and use them in different threads potentially at the same time ?

Comment: Hello mP; I would say not. I mean, it might work, depending on the JMS implementation and your implementation, but it is definitely contra-indicated. Instead, I would look at implementing some sort of server session pool where producers take a session from a pool, send a message and return the session to the pool.

Comment: How about creating new session for each transaction? does that make sense?