# Why QueueSession can create only one receiver in JMS?

Tags: session, jms, activemq-classic

I can make some senders to send some messages, but when I create two receivers in one Session, the first one works and the second one blocked. In debug, I see the queue list size which the second receiver received is zero. I found that session is made for one thread, I don't know whether this problem involves in the unsafe thread?

I use ActiveMQ implementation.

Answer (score 2):

A JMS Session is absolutely single threaded. As such, it can only have one active receiver. You have 2 options:

1. Use one connection with multiple sessions, each session having a receiver. Connections are thread safe and you can create many sessions from that single connections.
2. ActiveMQ gives you a number of options regarding [multiplexing multiple destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html), so rather than having multiple receivers, you might want to focus on one, but use ActiveMQ's facilities to create virtual destinations that will funnel all the messages you want through the one receiver.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335895/should-i-use-just-one-session-in-my-application-based-on-hornetq).