# Thread handling in Java HornetQ client

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, hornetq

I'm trying to understand how to deal with threads within a Java client that connects to HornetQ. I'm not getting a specific error but fail to understand how I'm expected to deal with threads in the first place (with respect to the HornetQ client and specifically `MessageHandler.onMessage()` -- threads in general are no problem to me).

In case this is relevant: I'm using `'org.hornetq:hornetq-server:2.4.7.Final'` to run the server embedded into my application. I don't intend this to make a difference. In my situation, that's just more convenient from an ops perspective than running a standalone server process.

What I did so far:

1. create an embedded server: `new EmbeddedHornetQ(),
   .setConfiguration()`
2. create a server locator: `HornetQClient.createServerLocator(false, new TransportConfiguration(InVMConnectorFactory.class.getName()))`
3. create a session factory: `serverLocator.createSessionFactory()`

Now it seems obvious to me that I can create a session using `hornetqClientSessionFactory.createSession()`, create a producer and consumer for that session, and deal with messages within a single thread using `.send()` and `.receive()`.

But I also discovered `consumer.setMessageHandler()`, and this tells me that I didn't understand threading in the client at all. I tried to use it, but then the consumer calls `messageHandler.onMessage()` in two threads that are distinct from the one that created the session. This seems to match my impression from looking at the code -- the HornetQ client uses a thread pool to dispatch messages.

This leaves me confused. The javadocs say that the session is a `"single-thread object"`, and the code agrees -- no obvious synchronization going on there. But with `onMessage()` being called in multiple threads, `message.acknowledge()` is also called in multiple threads, and that one just delegates to the session.
**How is this supposed to work? How would a scenario look in which MessageHandler does NOT access the session from multiple threads?**

Going further, **how would I send follow-up messages from within onMessage()?** I'm using HornetQ for a persistent "to-do" work queue, so sending follow-up messages is a typical use case for me. But again, within `onMessage()`, I'm in the wrong thread for accessing the session.

Note that I would be okay with staying away from MessageHandler and just using `send() / receive()` in a way that allows me to control threading. But I'm convinced that I don't understand the whole situation at all, and that combined with multi-threading is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Those follow-up messages: do you know upfront the destinations you are going to send them? Are follow-up destinations static or dynamic?

Comment: The address and queue are the same as for the original message -- a single queue of work units. Not sure what you mean by static/dynamic though. They are dynamic in the sense that the original work unit must be processed to know what follow-up messages must be generated.

Comment: I mean, why you are concerned about thread-safety of Session, if you can pass a producer to message handler (instead if Session).

Comment: For two reasons: First, the producer (ClientProducerImpl) seems to delegate to methods of the session without any additional synchronization. For example, send() to doSend() to session.startCall(). Second, even without producing any follow-up messages, I still have to acknowledge each message, which has the same problem: It delegates to the session without any additional synchronization.

Comment: onMessage() is for multiple concurrent consumers, each consumer have his own session. For example, if you like source code, check `org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. For re-sheduling message in the same queue you can create new message with property _HQ_SCHED_DELIVERY. Again, i suggest to use  `org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate` to send messages, it is care about connections, sessions and so on.

Comment: The code in DefaultMessageListenerContainer uses the JMS API, not the HornetQ API, so it didn't really help me. You are saying that each consumer has its own session -- how can I access that session? The onMessage() method gets called by HornetQ in threads started by HornetQ without any parameters. _HQ_SCHED_DELIVERY is to have a message appear at a defined time in the future and I don't see how it relates to the threading issue. I'm not using either JMS nor Spring, so JmsTemplate isn't within reach.

Comment: I checked to see if the messages link to different consumers based on the thread it gets called in (following your statement that onMessage is for multiple concurrent consumers, each with its own session). However, this isn't happening at all. The messages passed to onMessage() in different threads are all linked back to the *same* consumer, thus using the *same* session.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer part of your question, although I hope you've already fixed the issue by now.

Form the [HornetQ documentation on ClientConsumer](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/api/org/hornetq/api/core/client/ClientConsumer.html) (Emphasis mine):

> A ClientConsumer receives messages from HornetQ queues.
>   Messages can be consumed synchronously by using the receive() methods which will block until a message is received (or a timeout expires) or asynchronously by setting a MessageHandler.
>   **These 2 types of consumption are exclusive**: a ClientConsumer with a MessageHandler set will throw HornetQException if its receive() methods are called.

So you have two choices on handling message reception:

1. **Synchronize the reception yourself**

   - Do **not** provide a MessageListener to HornetQ
   - In your own cunsumer Thread, invoke `.receive()` or `.receive(long itmeout)` at your leisure
   - Retrieve the (optional) `ClientMessage` object returned by the call

     - **Pro:** Using the `Session` you hopefully carry in the Consumer you can forward the message as you see fit
     - **Con:** All this message handling will be sequential
2. **Delegate Thread synchronization to HornetQ**

   - Do **not** invoke `.receive()` on a Consumer
   - Provide a MessageListener implementation of `onMessage(ClientMessage)`

     - **Pro:** All the message handling will be concurrent and fast, hassle-free
     - **Con:** I do not think it possible to retrieve the `Session` from this object, as it is not exposed by the interface.
   - **Untested workaround:** In my application (which is in-vm like yours), I exposed the underlying, thread-safe [QueueConnection](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/javax/jms/class-use/QueueConnection.html) as a static variable available application-wide. From your MessageListener, you may invoke `QueueSession jmsSession = jmsConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);` on it to obtain a new Session and send your messages from it... This is probably [alright](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ShouldICacheJMSConnectionsAndJMSSessions) as far as I can [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335895/should-i-use-just-one-session-in-my-application-based-on-hornetq) because the Session object is not really re-created. I also did this because Sessions had a tendency to become stale.

---

I don't think you should want so much to be *in control* of your Message execution threads, especially transient Threads that merely forward messages. HornetQ has built-in Thread pools as you guessed, and reuses these objects efficiently.

Also as you know you don't need to be in a single Thread to access an object (like a Queue) so it doesn't matter if the Queue is accessed through multiple Threads, or even through multiple Sessions. You need only make sure a Session is only accesed by one Thread, and this is by design with MessageListener.